# Switch from Ubuntu to Windows 7

Tags: usb, windows

I want to switch from ubuntu to windows 7  using usb  because I don't have a dvd/cd drive pls help

Comment: question was not clear plz be specific.

Answer (score 2):

Use WinUSB

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:colingille/freshlight &&
apt-get update &&
apt-get install winusb`

Then:

`sudo winusb --install <iso path> <partition>`

You can always install Windows 7 inside a virtual machine if you are not gaming and have the best OS possible installed on your computer.

Comment: so i must write that in the termianl right but how like:     sudo add-apt-repository ppa:colingille/freshlight && apt-get update && apt-get install winusb

Comment: Copy and paste :)

Comment: sudo winusb --install <iso path> <partition>

Comment: I don't just want to make a bootable file i want to install winsdows and it keeps saying can't find autorun file. HELP!!!!!